# Avoiding same table joins

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have a table which has the main combination name,age,address based on the combination we have to find the id from `DUMMY_TEST` table.

And for that id in `DUMMY_TEST` table have to get all the  name,age,address combination which should be mapped with `DUMMY_ID_VALUE` table to get the Valuee column result.

Need the below given expected result without joining the same table `DUMMY_TEST` twice since it  has millions of record in real time will create perfomance issue.

Can anyone will help to create a query which will be good in performance without using the same table twice.

```
--table creation
CREATE TABLE DUMMY(NAME VARCHAR2(100),AGE VARCHAR2(100),ADDRESS VARCHAR2(100), ID VARCHAR2(100));
--data loading
INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES('SAM','30','ITALY','100');
INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES('RAGHU','20','VENICE','300');
INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES('TOM','40','JAPAN','200');

CREATE TABLE DUMMY_TEST(NAME VARCHAR2(100),AGE VARCHAR2(100),ADDRESS VARCHAR2(100), ID VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES('SAM','30','ITALY','100');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES('TOM','40','JAPAN','200');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES('BROSNAN','20','INDIA','100');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES('ARJUN','30','AMERICA','200');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES('SAMUEL','40','BERLIN','100');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES('RAM','60','GERMANY','200');

--table creation
CREATE TABLE DUMMY_ID_VALUE(ID VARCHAR2(100),VALUEE VARCHAR2(100));
--data loading
INSERT INTO DUMMY_ID_VALUE VALUES(100,'INCLUDED');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_ID_VALUE VALUES(200,'exclueded');
INSERT INTO DUMMY_ID_VALUE VALUES(300,'PARTIAL');
```

Query

```
SELECT DT.NAME,DT.AGE,DT.ADDRESS,DT.ID,DUMMY_ID_VALUE.VALUEE 
FROM DUMMY 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DUMMY_TEST A
  ON DUMMY.NAME = A.NAME AND DUMMY.AGE = A.AGE AND DUMMY.ADDRESS = A.ADDRESS 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DUMMY_TEST DT
  ON DT.ID = A.ID
  INNER JOIN DUMMY_ID_VALUE
  ON DUMMY_ID_VALUE.ID = DT.ID;
```

Actual result

```
NAME   AGE ADDRESS ID  VALUEE
---------------------------------
SAM        30  ITALY   100 INCLUDED
BROSNAN    20  INDIA   100 INCLUDED
SAMUEL 40  BERLIN  100 INCLUDED
```

Expected result:

```
NAME   AGE ADDRESS ID  VALUEE
---------------------------------
SAM        30  ITALY   100 INCLUDED
BROSNAN    20  INDIA   100 INCLUDED
SAMUEL 40  BERLIN  100 INCLUDED
RAGHU  20  VENICE  300 PARTIAL
```

Comment: your example returns 6 rows for me, are you really having only 3?

Comment: id is not a primary key

Comment: yes ...it will give 6 result..sry i missed it

Comment: Your data and expected results make no sense to me, and your explanation doesn't help to understand what you really want. You should rephrase this, and show better data

Comment: i need an approach to avoid joining same table twice

Comment: If you see in the query i have joined DUMMY_TEST  table twice to get the other combination based in the ID column.Is there any other way to get the result without joining the table twice.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two issues here, one (avoid double joining) is easy to solve:

```
select A.NAME, A.AGE, A.ADDRESS, A.ID, DUMMY_ID_VALUE.VALUEE 
FROM DUMMY
    left OUTER JOIN DUMMY_TEST A ON (DUMMY.NAME = A.NAME AND DUMMY.AGE = A.AGE AND DUMMY.ADDRESS = A.ADDRESS) or (DUMMY.ID = A.ID)
    INNER JOIN DUMMY_ID_VALUE on DUMMY_ID_VALUE.ID = A.ID
```

but i am not sure if it will improve performace.
The other one is that results you get do not meet your expectations, assuming logic you put in your query your result should be 6 rows.

Comment: Our scenario is like For one combination's(name,age,address) ID,we have to find the other possible combination's(nae,age,address)ID from the DUMMY_TEST table.With those combinaations ID we have to get the valuee data from DUUMMY_ID_VALUE table.

Comment: one combination
sam 30 italy 

while cheking in DUMMY_TEST for the same combination we will get
SAM 30 ITALY 100

then based on the ID which is 100 we have other combinations also like
--SAM 30 ITALY 100
BROSNAN 20 INDIA 100
SAMUEL 40 BERLIN 100

now for those cmbinations we have to check the valuee based on ID
for 100 it is INCLUDED

SAM 30 ITALY 100 INCLUDED
BROSNAN 20 INDIA 100 INCLUDED
SAMUEL 40 BERLIN 100 INCLUDED

Comment: sorry, i do not get your logic, try rewriting your query to produce proper results, then we can try to avoid double join

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, except for the `join`s.  I would go for:

```
SELECT DT.NAME, DT.AGE, DT.ADDRESS, DT.ID, DUMMY_ID_VALUE.VALUEE 
FROM DUMMY LEFT OUTER JOIN
     DUMMY_TEST A
     ON DUMMY.NAME = A.NAME AND DUMMY.AGE = A.AGE AND DUMMY.ADDRESS = A.ADDRESS LEFT OUTER JOIN
     DUMMY_TEST DT
     ON DT.ID = A.ID LEFT JOIN
     DUMMY_ID_VALUE
     ON DUMMY_ID_VALUE.ID = DT.ID;
```

The final join needs to be a `LEFT JOIN`.  For performance, your query is fine.  An index on `DUMMY_TEST(NAME, AGE, ADDRESS)` will help your performance.